# using quad to integrate function with respect to just one variable

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

is there any way i can integrate function of two variable, say

f=@(x) x^2 + x*y

over just x

tried quad(f, a, b)

but doesn't work, looking for alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but quad does not solve symbolic problems. It does only numerical integration.

```
syms x y
int(x^2 + x*y,x)
ans =
    (x^2*(2*x + 3*y))/6
```

The natural way to solve a symbolic problem is to use a symbolic tool.

From the followup, Anya wants something in-between. To steal the words of an old rock star named Mick, "You can't always get what you want."

Again, quad can't be used if you wish to integrate ONLY over x, as quad is an adaptive tool.

In SOME SIMPLE cases, you can use a simple tool like Simpson's rule to do the work. For example, suppose you wanted to solve the above problem, with x integrated over the interval [0 1]. For purposes of comparison, I'll do it symbolically first.

```
syms x y
res = int(x^2 + x*y,x);

subs(res,x,1) - subs(res,0)
ans =
   y/2 + 1/3
```

Now, lets try it using a numerical integration on x.

```
syms y
x = 0:.01:1;
coef = mod((0:100)',2)*2 + 2;
coef([1 end]) = 1;
coef = 0.01*coef/3;

(x.^2 + x.*y)*coef
ans =
   y/2 + 1/3
```

So in this very SIMPLE case, it did work. How about something a little more complicated? Integrate x*exp(x*y) over the interval [-1 1]. Again, a known form is accessible symbolically.

```
syms x y
res = int(x*exp(x*y),x);

res = subs(res,x,1) - subs(res,-1)
res =
   (exp(-y)*(y + 1))/y^2 + (exp(y)*(y - 1))/y^2
```

To test it out later, what value does this take on at y = 1/2?

```
vpa(subs(res,y,1/2))
ans =
   0.34174141687554424792549563431876
```

Lets try the same trick, using Simpson's rule.

```
syms y
x = -1:.01:1;
coef = mod((-100:100)',2)*2 + 2;
coef([1 end]) = 1;
coef = 0.01*coef/3;

res = (x.*exp(x*y))*coef
res =
   exp(y/2)/300 - exp(-y/2)/300 - exp(-y)/300 - exp(-y/4)/300 + exp(y/4)/300 - exp(-y/5)/750 + exp(y/5)/750 - exp(-(3*y)/4)/100 - exp(-(2*y)/5)/375 + exp((2*y)/5)/375 + exp((3*y)/4)/100 - exp(-(3*y)/5)/250 + exp((3*y)/5)/250 - (2*exp(-(4*y)/5))/375 + (2*exp((4*y)/5))/375 - exp(-y/10)/1500 + exp(y/10)/1500 - exp(-(3*y)/10)/500 + exp((3*y)/10)/500 - (7*exp(-(7*y)/10))/1500 + (7*exp((7*y)/10))/1500 - (3*exp(-(9*y)/10))/500 + (3*exp((9*y)/10))/500 - exp(-y/20)/1500 + exp(y/20)/1500 - exp(-(3*y)/20)/500 + exp((3*y)/20)/500 - exp(-y/25)/3750 + exp(y/25)/3750 - (7*exp(-(7*y)/20))/1500 - exp(-(2*y)/25)/1875 + exp((2*y)/25)/1875 + (7*exp((7*y)/20))/1500 - exp(-(3*y)/25)/1250 + exp((3*y)/25)/1250 - (3*exp(-(9*y)/20))/500 - (2*exp(-(4*y)/25))/1875 + (2*exp((4*y)/25))/1875 + (3*exp((9*y)/20))/500 - (11*exp(-(11*y)/20))/1500 - exp(-(6*y)/25)/625 + exp((6*y)/25)/625 + (11*exp((11*y)/20))/1500 - (7*exp(-(7*y)/25))/3750 + (7*exp((7*y)/25))/3750 - (13*exp(-(13*y)/20))/1500 - (4*exp(-(8*y)/25))/1875 + (4*exp((8*y)/25))/1875 + (13*exp((13*y)/20))/1500 - (3*exp(-(9*y)/25))/1250 + (3*exp((9*y)/25))/1250 - (11*exp(-(11*y)/25))/3750 + (11*exp((11*y)/25))/3750 - (17*exp(-(17*y)/20))/1500 - (2*exp(-(12*y)/25))/625 + (2*exp((12*y)/25))/625 + (17*exp((17*y)/20))/1500 - (13*exp(-(13*y)/25))/3750 + (13*exp((13*y)/25))/3750 - (19*exp(-(19*y)/20))/1500 - (7*exp(-(14*y)/25))/1875 + (7*exp((14*y)/25))/1875 + (19*exp((19*y)/20))/1500 - (8*exp(-(16*y)/25))/1875 + (8*exp((16*y)/25))/1875 - (17*exp(-(17*y)/25))/3750 + (17*exp((17*y)/25))/3750 - (3*exp(-(18*y)/25))/625 + (3*exp((18*y)/25))/625 - (19*exp(-(19*y)/25))/3750 + (19*exp((19*y)/25))/3750 - (7*exp(-(21*y)/25))/1250 + (7*exp((21*y)/25))/1250 - (11*exp(-(22*y)/25))/1875 + (11*exp((22*y)/25))/1875 - (23*exp(-(23*y)/25))/3750 + (23*exp((23*y)/25))/3750 - (4*exp(-(24*y)/25))/625 + (4*exp((24*y)/25))/625 - exp(-y/50)/7500 + exp(y/50)/7500 - exp(-(3*y)/50)/2500 + exp((3*y)/50)/2500 - (7*exp(-(7*y)/50))/7500 + (7*exp((7*y)/50))/7500 - (3*exp(-(9*y)/50))/2500 + (3*exp((9*y)/50))/2500 - (11*exp(-(11*y)/50))/7500 + (11*exp((11*y)/50))/7500 - (13*exp(-(13*y)/50))/7500 + (13*exp((13*y)/50))/7500 - (17*exp(-(17*y)/50))/7500 + (17*exp((17*y)/50))/7500 - (19*exp(-(19*y)/50))/7500 + (19*exp((19*y)/50))/7500 - (7*exp(-(21*y)/50))/2500 + (7*exp((21*y)/50))/2500 - (23*exp(-(23*y)/50))/7500 + (23*exp((23*y)/50))/7500 - (9*exp(-(27*y)/50))/2500 + (9*exp((27*y)/50))/2500 - (29*exp(-(29*y)/50))/7500 + (29*exp((29*y)/50))/7500 - (31*exp(-(31*y)/50))/7500 + (31*exp((31*y)/50))/7500 - (11*exp(-(33*y)/50))/2500 + (11*exp((33*y)/50))/2500 - (37*exp(-(37*y)/50))/7500 + (37*exp((37*y)/50))/7500 - (13*exp(-(39*y)/50))/2500 + (13*exp((39*y)/50))/2500 - (41*exp(-(41*y)/50))/7500 + (41*exp((41*y)/50))/7500 - (43*exp(-(43*y)/50))/7500 + (43*exp((43*y)/50))/7500 - (47*exp(-(47*y)/50))/7500 + (47*exp((47*y)/50))/7500 - (49*exp(-(49*y)/50))/7500 + (49*exp((49*y)/50))/7500 - exp(-y/100)/7500 + exp(y/100)/7500 - exp(-(3*y)/100)/2500 + exp((3*y)/100)/2500 - (7*exp(-(7*y)/100))/7500 + (7*exp((7*y)/100))/7500 - (3*exp(-(9*y)/100))/2500 + (3*exp((9*y)/100))/2500 - (11*exp(-(11*y)/100))/7500 + (11*exp((11*y)/100))/7500 - (13*exp(-(13*y)/100))/7500 + (13*exp((13*y)/100))/7500 - (17*exp(-(17*y)/100))/7500 + (17*exp((17*y)/100))/7500 - (19*exp(-(19*y)/100))/7500 + (19*exp((19*y)/100))/7500 - (7*exp(-(21*y)/100))/2500 + (7*exp((21*y)/100))/2500 - (23*exp(-(23*y)/100))/7500 + (23*exp((23*y)/100))/7500 - (9*exp(-(27*y)/100))/2500 + (9*exp((27*y)/100))/2500 - (29*exp(-(29*y)/100))/7500 + (29*exp((29*y)/100))/7500 - (31*exp(-(31*y)/100))/7500 + (31*exp((31*y)/100))/7500 - (11*exp(-(33*y)/100))/2500 + (11*exp((33*y)/100))/2500 - (37*exp(-(37*y)/100))/7500 + (37*exp((37*y)/100))/7500 - (13*exp(-(39*y)/100))/2500 + (13*exp((39*y)/100))/2500 - (41*exp(-(41*y)/100))/7500 + (41*exp((41*y)/100))/7500 - (43*exp(-(43*y)/100))/7500 + (43*exp((43*y)/100))/7500 - (47*exp(-(47*y)/100))/7500 + (47*exp((47*y)/100))/7500 - (49*exp(-(49*y)/100))/7500 + (49*exp((49*y)/100))/7500 - (17*exp(-(51*y)/100))/2500 + (17*exp((51*y)/100))/2500 - (53*exp(-(53*y)/100))/7500 + (53*exp((53*y)/100))/7500 - (19*exp(-(57*y)/100))/2500 + (19*exp((57*y)/100))/2500 - (59*exp(-(59*y)/100))/7500 + (59*exp((59*y)/100))/7500 - (61*exp(-(61*y)/100))/7500 + (61*exp((61*y)/100))/7500 - (21*exp(-(63*y)/100))/2500 + (21*exp((63*y)/100))/2500 - (67*exp(-(67*y)/100))/7500 + (67*exp((67*y)/100))/7500 - (23*exp(-(69*y)/100))/2500 + (23*exp((69*y)/100))/2500 - (71*exp(-(71*y)/100))/7500 + (71*exp((71*y)/100))/7500 - (73*exp(-(73*y)/100))/7500 + (73*exp((73*y)/100))/7500 - (77*exp(-(77*y)/100))/7500 + (77*exp((77*y)/100))/7500 - (79*exp(-(79*y)/100))/7500 + (79*exp((79*y)/100))/7500 - (27*exp(-(81*y)/100))/2500 + (27*exp((81*y)/100))/2500 - (83*exp(-(83*y)/100))/7500 + (83*exp((83*y)/100))/7500 - (29*exp(-(87*y)/100))/2500 + (29*exp((87*y)/100))/2500 - (89*exp(-(89*y)/100))/7500 + (89*exp((89*y)/100))/7500 - (91*exp(-(91*y)/100))/7500 + (91*exp((91*y)/100))/7500 - (31*exp(-(93*y)/100))/2500 + (31*exp((93*y)/100))/2500 - (97*exp(-(97*y)/100))/7500 + (97*exp((97*y)/100))/7500 - (33*exp(-(99*y)/100))/2500 + (33*exp((99*y)/100))/2500 + exp(y)/300
```

So I got a result, but its not the analytical one I wanted, and a bit of a nasty mess. Is it correct?

```
vpa(subs(res,y,1/2))
ans =
   0.34174141693463006644516447861307
```

I'll copy the analytical result from above so we can compare...

```
   0.34174141687554424792549563431876
```

As you can see, Simpson's rule, at a step size of 0.01 over [-1,1], did reasonably well, agreeing out to about 9 decimal digits.

There is no assurance that this technique will work as well on any more general kernel, but it might give you what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
y = 100; % whatever y is
a = 0;
b = 2;
% you'll need to vectorize the integrand function
f = @(x) x.*x + x.*y
val = quad(f, a, b);
```

However, if you are looking for an algebraic answer, you'll need to use the Symbolic Toolbox, or some other software, or your calculus book.  :-)

The whole "vectorize" thing comes from the [Mathworks quad documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad.html) that says:

> The function y = fun(x) should accept a vector argument x and return a vector result y, the integrand evaluated at each element of x.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @macduff. Yes i do in fact need an algebraic answer in a way i need an answer in a form of a function of y. I looked at symbolic integration using int, and that seems to do exactly what needed, except my function cannot be integrated precisely and need to be approximated, therefore function int wont work, i need something similar perhaps based on Simpson or Trapezoidal rule, but that also works with symbolic form. Anyone knows what that might be?